# Reopen "white people crimes" question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This question: ["White people" crime?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39627/white-people-crime) was closed as duplicate of this one: [Are white people more likely to commit mass murder in the United States?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20765/are-white-people-more-likely-to-commit-mass-murder-in-the-united-states)

They are clearly two very different questions:
1. Serial killers primary motivation is psychological gratification which is not the case with mass murderers. 
2. Mass shootings and sex crime are not addressed. Mass shootings as in Columbine and Newtown are also very distinct from other mass murder in that there are no rational reasons behind the violence. A mass murder may be committed for economic or political reasons (gang violence, terrorism), mass shootings are usually motivated by desire to pushing/hurt society and become infamous.

Your run of the mill mass murder does not have the psychological component that's at the heart of my question.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't involved in marking it as a duplicate. I went and had a look.

I would have closed the original question as unclear, so I am not ready to just reopen it myself.

You don't have a notable claim for any of the three questions you eventually ask - and certainly not the very specific definitions you insist upon.

The title is very vague, and needs fixing.

Please find an actual specific, notable claim, and focus the question on that one claim.

[I am not addressing your claims in this meta-question about the psychological motivations of the different types of crime. I don't think I have to understand or agree with them here.]